# Buggy UI when choosing icons in CE on Chrome/Firefox with Sitecore9u1

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, ribbon

Is it just in my installation or overall that ribbon `Configure` and button `Icon` are behaving incorrectly on Chrome and Firefox in `Sitecore 9 Update 1`?

Dialog box is hidden behind content tree:

[image: Incorrect look & feel of Icon ribbon button]

I need to scroll toolbar down to get to More Icons button:

[image: Bottom of the Icon dialog box]

**UPDATE:**
Bug reported to Sitecore Support and it is tracked with reference number 202331. Ask Sitecore Support to provide fix, it is working as expected after applying update package ;)

**WORKAROUND:**
I have summarized Vlad's suggestions + my own findings on various ways how to change icons in Sitecore in a blog post.

Take a look here -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/02/14/various-ways-of-changing-item-icons-in-sitecore/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like is a "bug" but  you can change in other way the icons and is much easier.

1. Select the template/item which you want to change the icon.
2. Click on the icon from the middle of content editor.

[image]

3. A new popup is open with all icons. You can choose category and icon.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Sitecore Climber . This is even faster ;)

Comment: Bug reported to Sitecore Support and it is tracked with reference number 202331. Ask Sitecore Support to provide fix, it is working as expected ;)

Comment: I have summarized various ways of changing icons in Sitecore in this article -> https://tothecore.sk/2018/02/14/various-ways-of-changing-item-icons-in-sitecore/

Comment: And I thought that I have installed Sitecore 9 wrong, so some features are unavailable.

Comment: @Sam - It is available - there is just small UI glitch :) After applying patch with reference number 202331 it will work as expected.